# Add regex string to array

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string

I need to add a regex string to an array but I get an error like "string can't implement in string[]".

This is the code:

```
foreach (string ss in fileLines)
{
    filelinesclean = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(ss, @"\s+", " ");
    MessageBox.Show("ok");
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\WriteLines.txt", filelinesclean);
}
```

Comment: `filelinesclean` is a string but `File.WriteAllLines` takes an *array* of strings for its second parameter. Perhaps you meant to use `File.WriteLine`.

Comment: filelinesclean is an array private string[] filelinesclean;

Comment: So that no-one proposes an answer which could result in running out of memory, how large is the (presumably) file from which you get `fileLines`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your requirement but it seems you are trying to use string in place of collection. This code may help.

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
foreach (string ss in fileLines)
{
   string filelinesclean = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(ss, @"\s+", " ");
   lines.Add(filelinesclean);
}
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\WriteLines.txt", lines);
```

I have keep your code as it is and added/updated few lines.

Comment: There's no point in overwriting the file on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

First add the following usings so you don't need to type out the entire namespaces for everything.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
```

The reason it doesn't work is because `File.WriteAllLines` expects a `IEnumerabl<string>` or a `string[]`, but you're passing a `string`.  Either use `File.AppendAllText` or just call `File.WriteAllLines` once after the `foreach` like this.

```
var lines = new List<string>();
foreach (string ss in fileLines)
{
    lines.Add(Regex.Replace(ss, @"\s+", " "));
}
MessageBox.Show("ok");
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\WriteLines.txt", lines);
```

Or like this using Linq

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    @"C:\Users\Public\WriteLines.txt",
    fileLines.Select(ss => Regex.Replace(ss, @"\s+", " "));
```

But based on some of your comments you might want to do the following

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    @"C:\Users\Public\WriteLines.txt",
    File.ReadLines(@"InputPath")
        .Select(ss => Regex.Replace(ss, @"\s+", " "));
```

Because of lazy initialization that will read in each line of your input file one at a time, do the regular expression replacement then write the line out before moving to the next line.  That will be scale-able if you need to run this on a very large file as it does not require the entire file to be in memory at one time.